# Rest API refactor

Tags: api, rest, oop, go

I want to ask if there is a better way to arrange this. Main concern is whether the store is set up in a good way and if passing Pointer to ProductRepository is a good idea or there are better ways but criticism towards all of it is welcome. I have this folder structure

```
.
├── Makefile
├── apiserver
├── cmd
│   └── apiserver
│       └── main.go
├── configs
│   └── apiserver.toml
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
└── internal
    └── app
        ├── apiserver
        │   ├── apiserver.go
        │   ├── config.go
        │   └── server.go
        ├── handlers
        │   ├── getAll.go
        │   └── getOne.go
        ├── model
        │   └── product.go
        └── store
            ├── product_repository.go
            └── store.go
```

My `server.go` file looks like

```golang
package apiserver

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"

    "github.com/vSterlin/sw-store/internal/app/handlers"
    "github.com/vSterlin/sw-store/internal/app/store"
)

type server struct {
    router *mux.Router
    logger *logrus.Logger
    store  *store.Store
}

func newServer(store *store.Store) *server {

    s := &server{
        router: mux.NewRouter(),
        logger: logrus.New(),
        store:  store,
    }

    s.configureRouter()
    return s
}

func (s *server) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    s.router.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}

func (s *server) configureRouter() {
    pr := s.store.Product()
    s.router.HandleFunc("/products", handlers.GetAllHandler(pr)).Methods("GET")
    s.router.HandleFunc("/products/{id}", handlers.GetOneHandler(pr)).Methods("GET")

}
```

`apiserver.go` which starts up

```golang
package apiserver

import (
    "database/sql"
    "net/http"

    // Postgres driver
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "github.com/vSterlin/sw-store/internal/app/store"
)

// Start starts up the server
func Start(config *Config) error {
    db, err := newDB(config.DatabaseURL)
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }
    defer db.Close()
    store := store.New(db)

    srv := newServer(store)
    return http.ListenAndServe(config.BindAddr, srv)
}

func newDB(databaseURL string) (*sql.DB, error) {
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", databaseURL)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if err := db.Ping(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return db, nil
}
```

`product_repository.go`

```golang
package store

import (
    "github.com/vSterlin/sw-store/internal/app/model"
)

type ProductRepository struct {
    store *Store
}

func (pr *ProductRepository) FindAll() ([]*model.Product, error) {

    rows, err := pr.store.db.Query("SELECT * FROM products;")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    pmArr := []*model.Product{}
    for rows.Next() {
        pm := &model.Product{}
        rows.Scan(&pm.ID, &pm.Name, &pm.Price, &pm.Description, &pm.CreatedAt, &pm.UpdatedAt)
        pmArr = append(pmArr, pm)
    }
    return pmArr, nil

}
func (pr *ProductRepository) FindById(id int) (*model.Product, error) {
    row := pr.store.db.QueryRow("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=$1;", id)
    pm := &model.Product{}

    err := row.Scan(&pm.ID, &pm.Name, &pm.Price, &pm.Description, &pm.CreatedAt, &pm.UpdatedAt)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return pm, nil
}
```

and `store.go` is

```golang
package store

import (
    "database/sql"
)

type Store struct {
    db                *sql.DB
    productRepository *ProductRepository
}

func New(db *sql.DB) *Store {
    return &Store{
        db: db,
    }
}

func (s *Store) Product() *ProductRepository {
    if s.productRepository != nil {
        return s.productRepository
    }

    s.productRepository = &ProductRepository{
        store: s,
    }

    return s.productRepository
}
```

Comment: the `*sql.DB` has`MaxConnections` and `MaxIdle` time. The start function starts both connection to database and starts the server, ideally it would do one thing. Does writing `Product()` method on `*store` have any advantage? you could also pass the databse connection as a variable or call it as a service.`row := pr.store.db.QueryRow("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=$1;", id)` you could check for `Error.NoRows` before returning as error, because it would mean there is a nil value to return, but there is no actual error.

Comment: @whitespace Product() is kind of a getter for productRepository that’s on Store. You can see it used in configureRouter() in server.go file.

Comment: i guess the reason for passing this store object to handler is to call the model within handler. this cripples your ability to write tests for logic you wrote in handler. Ideally you should be able to either write the model methods to take in the `*sql.DB` connection(just like your handler does as a parameter) or set this as a service which can be called within each model. This code will be a lot more testable.

Comment: your db instance should be a parameter of your repositories methods to enable transactionnal usage of those methods accross multiple calls. Having it as a property of the store prevents that. The start method actively ignores database connection error, i see no good reason for that.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).